# CMS Made Simple, trouble including file

Tags: content-management-system, php, cmsmadesimple

I have a little problem with using the php include() within user defined tags.
like in cmsms manual described you can add php code via user defined tags into your cmsms page. I tried hard, but it is not working.
This is the code I just wanna add:

```
<?php
    $site="true";
    include("/home/www/web23/html/wbt/index.php");
?>
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: include(wp.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
   No such file or directory in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsms\lib\classes\class.usertagoperations.inc.php(260) :
     eval()'d code on line 1 
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'wp.php' for inclusion 
   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
     in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsms\lib\classes\class.usertagoperations.inc.php(260) :
      eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: :( I M New in CMS MS ... Help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting `/home/www/`

It shouldn't make any difference. At least in windows it doesn't

Comment: I alredy delere it .. but still i facing same problem so for that what can i do ?

Comment: it looks like a file is missing else i have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: http://forum.cmsmadesimple.org/viewtopic.php?t=43138           you can check here......

Comment: sorry i can't help you but what i should do is look if there is a update and else flow all the included pages to find the error

Comment: Its ok ... I dnt knw i change the whole logic now its completed thank you :)